# How to create automatic path on a java application

Tags: java

I'm creating a little application to take a picture of my screen. I can save it automatically on my desktop using this path:

> ```
> String FILENAME = "C:\\Users\\obed\\Desktop\\" + x + ".png";
>  ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(FILENAME));
> ```

where Obed is my username. How can I change "obed" automatically to the user´s pc name, so in that way I can run my application on any computer?

Answer (score 5):

You can get the user's home directory from the system property `user.home`:

```
String FILENAME = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\" + x + ".png";
```